# typescript return triggering before await response

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-dynamodb

I am working with Serverless to create a REST get endpoint. The intention is to call this endpoint and return a value from the DynamoDB query (the `body` tag to be specific). Problem I'm having is that the response from this endpoint is `{}` when its invoked. I believe that is because the `return` is being invoked before the query data is available.

However, I'm using the `await` keyword when making the query, so I would assume I would be getting back the actual data and not the promise.

Here is my code:

```
import { APIGatewayProxyHandler } from 'aws-lambda';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

export const getorder: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (event, _context) => {
  var orderRefId = +event.queryStringParameters.orderRefId;

  var params = {
    TableName: 'MYTABLENAME',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'orderRefId = :orderRefId',
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{
      ':orderRefId': orderRefId
    }
  }

  let result = await dynamoDB.query(params).promise();

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      order: result.Items[0].body
    })
  };
}
```

Any thoughts on why the `return` is firing before the `result` has it's data?

Comment: It's not; `await` yields control until the promise returned by `.promise()` settles.

Comment: The response will never be `{}` just because `result` has the wrong value. Can you show us how `getorder` is called, please? My guess would be that the caller doesn't wait for the promise and instead stringifies it into a property-less object.

Comment: @Bergi getorder is called by AWS API Gateway as this is used in AWS Lambda.

Comment: I should clarify, the response isn't `{}` rather the result of the promise in the `result` variable is not awaited, instead the `getorder` just returns an empty body.

Comment: @BrandonW Does AWS API Gateway support promises? And you should post the real response. Also I'm pretty sure that `result` is properly awaited and does contain an object, otherwise the `result.Items[0].body` expression would throw an expression.

Comment: @Bergi the expression `result.Items[0].body` does in fact throw an exception: `Serverless: Failure: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Ultimately I am trying to get the fulfilled response from the DynamoDB query. I suppose I am unsure how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem I'm having is that the response from this endpoint is {} when its invoked.

It can never be `{}`. It is most likely a `Promise`, and you need to cater for that.

## Note

`async` functions *always* return a promise.